# Java class "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, constructor

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  
    TeamLeader cannot be resolved to a type

    at TeamLeadDemo.main(TeamLeadDemo.java:26)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    public String empName, empNumber, hireDate;    

    public class TeamLeadDemo {}

    public Employee(String empName, String empNumber, String hireDate) {
        this.setEmpName(empName);
        this.setEmpNumber(empNumber);
        this.setHireDate(hireDate);
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
         this.empName = empName;
    }
        public void setEmpNumber(String empNumber) {
         this.empNumber = empNumber;
    }
    public void setHireDate(String hireDate) {
         this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public String getEmpNumber() {
        return empNumber;
    }
    public String getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }

    public class ShiftSupervisor extends Employee {
        public double annualSalary, annualProduction;
        //constructor
        public ShiftSupervisor(String empName, String empNumber,
                               String hireDate, double annualSalary,
                               double annualProduction) {
            super(empName,empNumber, hireDate);
            this.setAnnualSalary(annualSalary);
            this.setAnnualProduction(annualProduction);
        }

        public double getAnnualSalary() {
            return annualSalary;
        }
        public double getAnnualProduction() {
            return annualProduction;
        }
        public void setAnnualSalary(double annualSalary) {
            this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
        }
        public void setAnnualProduction(double annualProduction) {
            this.annualProduction = annualProduction;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Name: "+ getEmpName() + "\nEmpID: "+ getEmpNumber()
                   + "\nHire Date: "+ getHireDate() + "\nAnnual Salary: "
                   + annualSalary + "\nProduction: "+ annualProduction;
        }

        public class employeeStart {
            public void main(String[] args) {
                String name, id, date;
                double sal, prod;

                //create scanner object
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                //inputting data
                System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
                name = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter id: ");
                id = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Hire Date: ");
                date = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Annual: ");
                sal = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter production: ");
                prod = keyboard.nextDouble();

                //instantiating object
                ShiftSupervisor pw = new ShiftSupervisor(name, id, date, sal, prod);

                //outputting data
                System.out.println("Employee Details: \n" + pw);
            }
        }
        public class TeamLeader {
            public double monthlyBonus;
            public int minTraining, trainingPresent;    

            public TeamLeader(double monthlyBonus, int minTraining, int trainingPresent) {
                this.setMonthlyBonus(monthlyBonus);
                this.setMinTraining(minTraining);
                this.addtrainingPresent(trainingPresent);                    
            }

            public void setMonthlyBonus(double monthlyBonus) {
                this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;
            }
            public void setMinTraining(int minTraining) {
                this.minTraining = minTraining;
            }
            public void setTrainingPresent(int t) {
                trainingPresent = t;
            }
            public void addtrainingPresent(int hours) {
                trainingPresent += hours;
            }
            public double getMonthlyBonus() {
                return monthlyBonus;
            }
            public int getMinTraining() {
                return minTraining;
            }
            public int getTrainingPresent() {
                return trainingPresent;
            }
            public String toString() {
                return "Bonus: "+ getMonthlyBonus() + "\nMinimum Training: "
                + getMinTraining() + "\nAttendence: "+ getTrainingPresent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, I declared this in a separate class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeamLeadDemo extends Employee {
    public TeamLeadDemo(String empName, String empNumber, String hireDate) {
        super(empName, empNumber, hireDate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double sal;
    int min, atten;

    //create scanner object
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //inputting data
    System.out.println("Enter minimum training: ");
    min = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter id: ");
    atten = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Bonus: ");
    sal = keyboard.nextDouble();

    //instantiating object
    ShiftSupervisor pw = new TeamLeader(sal, min, atten);

    //outputting data
    System.out.println("Employee Details:\n" + pw);

    }
}
```

What is causing this error and how might I resolve it?

EDIT: Indentation, whitespace, naming conventions and readability issues have been somewhat addressed.

Comment: Your naming conventions are just about as terrible as well. [Please fix them.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: It means that if you get a good answer to your question, you need to click on the checkmark next to it. That will give both you and the answerer rep points, and it's a great way of saying "thank you". Not doing so is considered rude. It may be a good idea to go through all your questions and accept answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `TeamLeader` appears to be an inner class (hard to tell, your indentation is bad), and since it's not static, you can't instantiate it by itself.

You either need to make `TeamLeader` its own class, or make it a `static` class and instantiate it as `Employee.TeamLeader` (or whatever the parent class is, your indentation is really not helpful here).

Comment: I don't understand why buy eclipse asked me to declare a new class. public class TeamLeader extends ShiftSupervisor 
{

}  Then it asked me to declare another class 
public class ShiftSupervisor 
{

}

Comment: Upvoted for indentation being bad. Coding style and consistency is a beautiful and extremely helpful thing.

Answer (score 11):

If this problem is with maven project then right-click **Maven > Update Project** should solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Your exception message says this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: **Unresolved compilation problem**: TeamLeader cannot be resolved to a type

This means that you have tried to run a program that used some class that has not compiled correctly.

Go back and fix the compilation error(s).

It is not clear what the fix for the compilation error should be, but the error is saying that it cannot find a class called `TeamLeader`.  Perhaps it doesn't exist.  Perhaps it is in a different package.  Perhaps you haven't compiled it.  Perhaps something else.

---

Looking at the code, I think the problem is that you have defined *two distinct classes* called `TeamLeadDemo`, one as a nested class of `Employee` and the second as a top-level class.  Furthermore the second of these is attempting to use `TeamLeader` ... but the `TeamLeader` class that you have actually declared is nested 2 levels down in `Employee`; i.e. its real name is `Employee.ShiftSupervisor.TeamLeader`.

This is all a bit nonsensical.

By the look of it, you defined a whole bunch of classes in the same file ("Employee.java") without much understanding of what it means to put one class inside another.  Most likely, each of those classes should be declared in its own file.  And most likely you should just delete the nested `TeamLeadDemo` class.

Answer (score 0):

That error can appear also if you create the inner class by moving it from somewhere, and with reorganization, you put the import line for that inner class in its outer class file. After that the inner class `cannot be resolved to a type` anywhere. Automatic insert of import won't help.

You have not published the import section of the outer class and we cannot check that variant. Check for it, and if the excessive import is there, remove it.

And if you work in Eclipse, it is very probable you need to clean the project after that.