# How should i get data by calling javaclass method from JSP using Getters Method?

Tags: java, jsp

> .Classpath file
>
> ```html
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <classpath>
>     <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="src" path="images"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre1.8.0_231">
>         <attributes>
>             <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
>         </attributes>
>     </classpathentry>
>     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v8.0">
>         <attributes>
>             <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
>         </attributes>
>     </classpathentry>
>     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/BABU/my_soft/jar_files/ojdbc14.jar"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/BABU/my_soft/jar_files/mysql-connector.jar"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/BABU/my_soft/jar_files/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"/>
>     <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
> </classpath>
> ```

** getting data from DB using java class with two methods getCid(),getName() But i'm getting error.what should i do?**
[CLICK HERE to image-This is the page where i'm adding products from ADMIN_DB to User_DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwaqr.png)

[CLICK HERE to image-This is the Error-code getting. After by clicking ADD button in Addingpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvxZ5.jpg)

> ERROR-PAGE

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\HCL\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\myregistration\org\apache\jsp\addcartdb_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. daopack.DaoData resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\HCL\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\myregistration\org\apache\jsp\addcartdb_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. mypack.FetchData resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /addcartdb.jsp
DaoData cannot be resolved to a type
26: 
27:     //SelectData sd = new SelectData();
28:     //FetchData fd = new FetchData();
29:     DaoData dd = new DaoData();
30:     
31:     String cid = dd.getCid(mail);;
32:     


An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /addcartdb.jsp
DaoData cannot be resolved to a type
26: 
27:     //SelectData sd = new SelectData();
28:     //FetchData fd = new FetchData();
29:     DaoData dd = new DaoData();
30:     
31:     String cid = dd.getCid(mail);;
32:     


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
```

> JSP Code where i'm trying to call Methods getCid(),getName()

```html
<%@page import="daopack.DaoData"%>
<%@page import="mypack.FetchData" %>

<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>addcartdb</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try {
    
    String pname = request.getParameter("pname");
    int pprice = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pprice"));
    int tq = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tq"));
    
    String mail = (String)session.getAttribute("mail");
    

    
    DaoData dd = new DaoData();
    
    String cid = dd.getCid(mail);;
    
    
     System.out.print(" addcartdb..cid...: "+cid+"\n");
     
     String name2 = dd.getName(mail);
     
     System.out.print("\n addcartdb..name...: "+name2+"\n");
    
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srm";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String sql=" insert into customerstock(cid,name,pname,pprice,tq)values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    
    
    
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, cid);
    ps.setString(2, name2);
    ps.setString(3, pname);
    ps.setInt(4, pprice);
    ps.setInt(5, tq);
    
    
    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    out.print(" executed  "+i);
    if (i > 0) {
        out.print("<script>");
        out.print("alert('Added..!'); window.location.href='add_cart.jsp';");
        out.print("</script>");

    }
//}

} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e);
}

System.out.println(" printed...Addcartdb....3");


%>
</body>
</html>
```

> DaoDta.java file

```
package daopack;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DaoData {

private static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srm";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
      
        return con;
        
    }

private String cid;
private String name;

public String getCid(String mail) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection con = getConnection();
    if(con!=null)
    System.out.println("\n Connected...!  "+con+"\n");
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select cid from registar where mail='"+mail+"'");
        ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
        cid=rs.getString("cid");
        }
        
        con.close();
    return cid;
}

public String getName(String mail) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    
    System.out.println("\nDaoData---:"+mail+"\n");
    Connection con = getConnection();
    if(con!=null)
        System.out.println("\n Connected...!  "+con+"\n");  
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select cid from registar where mail='"+mail+"'");
        ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
        name=rs.getString("cid");
        }
        
        
    con.close();
    
    return name;
}



}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125107/java-class-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) might help .

Comment: Are your class files on the classpath?  Do you have?  <yourWebapoRootFolder>/WEB-INF/classes/daopack/DaoData.class

Comment: YES, i have /WEB-INF/classes/daopack/DaoData.class and  it is showing unable to compile

Comment: Please try creating a DaoData object in a  Servlet.  Maybe you will get a better error message.

Comment: I  assume that you tried cleaning your project in eclipse  and restarting  Tomcat.

Comment: A  desperate  try is  to use  <%@page import="daopack.*"%>

Comment: @rickz , i already tried <%@page import="daopack.DaoData"%> AND <%@page import="daopack.*"%>. still no change